# Query to search in multiple tables + Specify the returned value

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, extjs, extjs4

My original query is taking a term from text field and start searching for it in two columns of one table [in order in create an autocomplete]

```
$query = $_GET['query'];      
$sql ="SELECT f_name, l_name FROM student WHERE (f_name ILIKE '%$query%' OR l_name ILIKE '%$query%');
$result = pg_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
           {  
            $names[] = array('f_name' => $row[0], 'l_name' => $row[1]);
           }

    $name_list = array();
    $name_list['success']       = true;
    $name_list['names']     = $names;


    $name_list['totalCount']    = count( $name_list['names'] );

echo json_encode($name_list);
```

No I want to add an extra criteria from another table (e.g: subject), So the user can enter a part of students first name, last name or subject. also I need to know the type of returned value, I mean if this is a name or a subject. so i can show a small icon depending on the type.

This is the model so you can imagine how I am doing it:

```
     Ext.define("Post", {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
           proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
        url: 'app/search.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'names',

        autoLoad: true,
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    },

    fields: ['f_name','l_name'
, {
                    name : 'display',
                    convert : function(v, rec) {                        
                        return rec.get('f_name') + ',' + rec.get('l_name');
                    }
                }
    ]
    });
```

So if user entered: mat
the result would be:

> Mathio,Jay << student's first and last name
>
> Mark,Matt << student's first and last name

After my changes it should be like:

> Mathio,Jay << student's first and last name
>
> Mark,Matt << student's first and last name
>
> Mathematics << subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is adjust your original query to pick up the subject the student is enrolled in (via a join)

```
SELECT f_name, l_name, subj.name
FROM student stud
JOIN subjects subj on subj.stud_id=stud.stud_id
WHERE (f_name ILIKE '%$query%' OR l_name ILIKE '%$query%' 
                               OR subj.name ILIKE '%query%');
```

Now, you probably have a multiple relationship between student and subject, so you'll need to adjust the SQL code to accommodate that.   If you add your table structures, someone can jump in and show you how to do the actual join you need...

```
SELECT 'STUD' as theFlag,f_name, l_name, '' as SubjName
FROM student stud
WHERE (f_name ILIKE '%$query%' OR l_name ILIKE '%$query%')
UNION
SELECT 'SUBJ' as theFlag,'' as f_name,'' as l_name, subj.name as SubjName
FROM subject
WHERE (subj.name ILIKE '%query%');
```

You'll now get a record back with 4 columns.   The first column indicates the source and will be either STUD or SUBJ.    For STUD record, first and last name will be populated and the SubjName field will be blank.  For SUBJ record, first and last name will be blank, but SubjName will be populated...

The only caveat would be if a record was found in both.   For that, you need to decide which one you want to use...

Comment: Thanks, but i need the search of subject to be simple, not related to students. So the text field could be used to search for students or any subject in general

Comment: Thank you! but if I found the term in both, can I get them all with flag tells me it it is a student or subject?

Comment: the first column in the query should tell you whether it is a subject or a student...

Comment: Thank you! it works finally! Now i need to re-configure the other parts so the both values can be displayed at the text field. I'd be happy if you take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529206/extjs-combo-with-templates-to-display-multiple-values